# CSS font size scaling jitter

Tags: css, text, scale, transition, jitter

I'm trying to scale font sizes to create a fish eye lens effect on hover.

Using CSS to increase the font size with transition causes a jitter effect.

Using transform scale creates an undesirable effect where the left hand side of the text moves over to the left a little before scaling up.

I've created a pen to illustrate the 2 effects side by side. Ideally, I'd like the effect on the left with the smoothness of the right

https://codepen.io/sygad1/pen/QMWqXy

Any ideas to achieve this?

Cheers

HTML

```
  <ul class="fish-eye-text-size">
    <li>Font size scaling</li>
    <li>Menu item one</li>
    <li>Menu item two</li>
    <li>Menu item three</li>
    <li>Menu item four</li>
    <li>Menu item five</li>
    <li>Menu item six</li>
    <li>Menu item seven</li>
    <li>Menu item eight</li>
    <li>Menu item nine</li>
    <li>Menu item ten</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="fish-eye-scaling">
    <li>CSS scaling</li>
    <li>Menu item one</li>
    <li>Menu item two</li>
    <li>Menu item three</li>
    <li>Menu item four</li>
    <li>Menu item five</li>
    <li>Menu item six</li>
    <li>Menu item seven</li>
    <li>Menu item eight</li>
    <li>Menu item nine</li>
    <li>Menu item ten</li>
  </ul>
```

SCSS

```
//Text size
.mediumText {
  font-size:1.4rem;
}
.largeText {
  font-size:1.7rem;
}



// CSS Scaling
.mediumScale {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
.largeScale {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}




ul {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  width:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
  background:#e1e1e1;

  li {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:all 0.4s;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    will-change: transform;
  } 

}
```

JS

```
// Font size
$(".fish-eye-text-size li").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).addClass("largeText");
  $(this).next().addClass("mediumText");
  $(this).prev().addClass("mediumText");
});

$(".fish-eye-text-size li").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("largeText");
  $(this).next().removeClass("mediumText");
  $(this).prev().removeClass("mediumText");
});

// CSS Scaling
$(".fish-eye-scaling li").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).addClass("largeScale");
  $(this).next().addClass("mediumScale");
  $(this).prev().addClass("mediumScale");
});

$(".fish-eye-scaling li").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("largeScale");
  $(this).next().removeClass("mediumScale");
  $(this).prev().removeClass("mediumScale");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the transform origin implicitly changes on hover from default `50% 50%` to `0% 50%`, hence the jittering. You should set `transform-origin: 10px 50%;` (10px instead of 0 because we aim to fix the position of first letter, not the padding outer edge, so we set the transform origin to the inner edge of the padding area) [to the default state of `li`](https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/QMweGq) and remove it from `.mediumScale`/`.largeScale` classes.